# Getting shared image from Google Photos app

Tags: android, security, google-photos

My problem the next: my app receives image from Google Photos by intent filter in manifest

```
<intent-filter android:label="@string/app_name">
        <action android:name="android.intent.action.SEND" />
        <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />

        <data android:mimeType="text/*" />
        <data android:mimeType="image/*" />
    </intent-filter>
```

then I get uri like this:

```
mSharedImageUri = intent.getParcelableExtra(Intent.EXTRA_STREAM);
```

then I send event to Fragment and start another Activity with this Fragment which is received event with shared image uri. Request "READ_EXTERNAL" permission, after permission is granted uses 
`getContentResolver().openInputStream(uri)`
to get Exif data, and at the moment I get the next:

```
java.lang.RuntimeException: Failure delivering result ResultInfo{who=@android:requestPermissions:, request=75542, result=-1, data=Intent { act=android.content.pm.action.REQUEST_PERMISSIONS (has extras) }} to activity {com.my.app/com.my.app.activities.Activity}: java.lang.SecurityException: Permission Denial: opening provider com.google.android.apps.photos.contentprovider.impl.MediaContentProvider from ProcessRecord{be2762c 9157:com.my.app/u0a931} (pid=9157, uid=10931) that is not exported from uid 10086
                                                                     at android.app.ActivityThread.deliverResults(ActivityThread.java:3940)
                                                                     at android.app.ActivityThread.handleSendResult(ActivityThread.java:3983)
                                                                     at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap16(ActivityThread.java)
                                                                     at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1548)
                                                                     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:111)
                                                                     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:207)
                                                                     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5765)
                                                                     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
                                                                     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:789)
                                                                     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:679)
                                                                  Caused by: java.lang.SecurityException: Permission Denial: opening provider com.google.android.apps.photos.contentprovider.impl.MediaContentProvider from ProcessRecord{be2762c 9157:com.my.app/u0a931} (pid=9157, uid=10931) that is not exported from uid 10086
```

But if requesting of permission happens on the first Activity or permission is granted at the moment all works fine.
Could you please give me an advice. It was worked earlier, for example about a mounth ago.

Comment: Hello, did you find any solution for this, i am also facing this issue.Please help

Comment: @BHARATGUPTA Yes, I just request READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE in Activity which receives image URI, and after granting permission all works fine.

Comment: Hey Thanks. But the problem was some thing different. Actually i was passing the URI to another activity that was giving problem. The actual way is to get the FILE from URI in same activity which request the Google photos app and pass the FILE in your app.

Answer (score 1):

> and start another Activity with this Fragment which is received event with shared image uri

Call `addFlags(Intent.FLAG_GRANT_READ_URI_PERMISSION)` on the `Intent` that you use to deliver the `Uri` to the other activity. Otherwise, that activity will not have access to the content.

Comment: Sorry, but it doesn't work. I got the same stacktrace

Comment: May be do you have any other suggestions? Or could you please explain why it's happens.

Comment: @RuslanLeshchenko: Please edit your question to show both how you are starting the second activity and how that activity is generating the stack trace.

Comment: The thing is exception is generated in Fragment.
`then I send event to Fragment and start another Activity with this Fragment which is received event with shared image uri.` With help Event Bus I send event with image uri to Fragment then start an Activity which contains this Fragment, when Fragment is started, event is catched and permission is requested. After permission is granted I use `getContentResolver().openInputStream(uri)` to get Exif data, and at the moment I get the exception.

Comment: I am facing the same issue does anybody got solution ?